# How do I get accurate entry paths in Expression Engine search results?

Tags: expressionengine

I am working to implement advanced search on a site and need some help getting more accurate paths to entries in the search results page.

I am using a modified advanced search form:

```
    {exp:search:advanced_form result_page="search/advanced_results"} 
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend>{lang:search_by_keyword}</legend>
    <input type="text" class="input" maxlength="100" size="40" name="keywords" style="width:100%;" />
    <div class="default">
    <select name="search_in">
        <option value="titles" selected="selected">{lang:search_in_titles}</option>
        <option value="entries" selected="selected">{lang:search_in_entries}</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="default">
        <select name="where">
            <option value="exact" selected="selected">{lang:exact_phrase_match}</option>
            <option value="any">{lang:search_any_words}</option>
            <option value="all" >{lang:search_all_words}</option>
            <option value="word" >{lang:search_exact_word}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</fieldset>

<div class="defaultBold">{lang:channels}</div>
    <select id="channel_id" name='channel_id[]' class='multiselect' size='15' multiple='multiple' onchange='changemenu(this.selectedIndex);'>
        {channel_names}
    </select>

<div class="defaultBold">{lang:categories}</div>
    <select name='cat_id[]' size='18' class='multiselect' multiple='multiple'>
        <option value='all' selected="selected">{lang:any_category}</option>
    </select>

<div class='searchSubmit'>
    <input type='submit' value='Search' class='submit' />
</div>
{/exp:search:advanced_form}
</body>
```

and the standard search results code:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th>{lang:title}</th>
<th>{lang:excerpt}</th>
<th>{lang:author}</th>
<th>{lang:date}</th>
<th>{lang:total_comments}</th>
<th>{lang:recent_comments}</th>
</tr>

{exp:search:search_results switch="resultRowOne|resultRowTwo"}

<tr class="{switch}">
<td width="30%" valign="top"><b><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></b></td>
<td width="30%" valign="top">{excerpt}</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top"><a href="{member_path='member/index'}">{author}</a></td>
<td width="10%" valign="top">{entry_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top">{comment_total}</td>
<td width="10%" valign="top">{recent_comment_date format="%m/%d/%y"}</td>
</tr>

{/exp:search:search_results}

</table>
```

The only problem is that the {auto_path} is anything but accurate, does not link to the entry and basically tries to piggyback off the home page. Is there a way secure more accurate paths? I know Google Search can do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin → Channel Administration → Channels → Edit Preferences → Path Settings. There you enter the base URL for your `auto_path` or `id_auto_path`.

So entering **/news/entry/** would yield **/news/entry/my-new-url-title** in your search results.

Answer (score 1):

The `{auto_path}` variable in the [Search Results Tag](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/modules/search/results.html#var_auto_path) is automatically be determined by the **Search Results URL** preference setting for the channel in Channel Management.

You can find this preference in the Control Panel at: **Admin > Channel Administration > Channel Preferences:**[image]